# Change foreign key column name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have a `Project` migration class like this:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :projects do |t|
   t.string :title
   t.text :description
   t.boolean :public
   t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

It creates a column name `user_id` in projects table but I want to name the column `owner_id` so I can use `project.owner` instead of `project.user`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

OR

```
$ rails g migration ChangeForeignKeyForProjects

# db/migrate/change_foreign_key_for_projects.rb
class ChangeForeignKeyForProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      rename_column :projects, :user_id, :owner_id
   end
end
```

then:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I was happy to find out that `rename_column` also takes care of renaming indexes.

Comment: You can also use [`change_table`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table) with `t.rename`

Comment: I get unknown attribute `new_id`?